# Imagemagick 'convert': how to simply create thumbnails for a folder of images and retain their filename?

Tags: image-processing, batch-file, imagemagick

I have a folder /images/

I'd like to use imagemagick to go through every image in that folder and create a thumbnail and store it in

/images/thumbs

and retain the filename

I can't find any example of how to do that (batch style) using terminal?

Answer (score 4):

Now there is a way to do that with imageMagick itself (without shell commands) which has the bonus of being platform-independent.

According to the [imagemagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/) you can do

```
mogrify  -format gif -path thumbs -thumbnail 100x100 *.jpg
```

to create thumbnails for all your jpg's in `thumbs/`

Just make sure that the directory exists.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone gets on this page as from 2020, here is our one line solution from the command line with Imagemagick v7.0.10-23:

```
mogrify -path 'full-server-path/thumbnails/' -resize 50%  *
```

Where '-path' is the directory from which you want to convert into the subdir 'thumbnails'.
So, all files in your current dir will be stored with the same filename in /thumbnails, but at 50% of the original.

Comment: In IM 7, use magick mogrify, not mogrify. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

Answer (score 0):

Here is a skeleton for a Windows batch script you can base your script on:

```
md thumbs
for %%f in (*.jpg) do (
  gm convert -convert_commands_here %%f thumbs\%%~nf.jpg 
)
```

This batch script processes all `.jpg` files in the current directory and saves the converted images into a `thumbs` subdirectory

Comment: thanks, i tried: `bash-3.2$ for %%f in (*.jpg) do (   /usr/local/bin/convert  -thumbnail  186x100^  %%f new_thumbs\%%~nf.jpg )` and got: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: it's a Windows batch, sorry about the misunderstanding